# RubyMine: expected ; or end of line error after some colon

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rubymine

My rails project works just fine. But rubymine highlights error `expected ; or end of line` after some `colon :`. For example

```
before_action :set_answer, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
format.html { redirect_to @answer, notice: 'Answer was successfully created.' }
```

In above rubymine highlights error after `only:`  and `notice:`. But it doesn't highlight error after `:set_answer, :show, :edit, :update or :destroy`.

What is the reason for this and How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

With later RubyMine versions on Mac: Go to Preferences -> 'Language & Frameworks' -> 'Ruby SDK and Gems', and change to Ruby 2.0 SDK Restart and it should work.